# Error while connecting Oozie server: connection timed out

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am trying to run pig program using oozie in command prompt but i am getting error like

```
Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection timed out ]. Trying after 1 sec. Retry count = 1
Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection timed out ]. Trying after 2 sec. Retry count = 2
Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection timed out ]. Trying after 4 sec. Retry count = 3
Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection timed out ]. Trying after 8 sec. Retry count = 4
Error: IO_ERROR : java.io.IOException: Error while connecting Oozie server. No of retries = 4. Exception = Connection timed out
```

and i am running this command

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config job.properties -run
```

Comment: Well, is Oozie server running on your local machine?

Comment: actually i am not able find out that.

Comment: i am using SSH secure shell, and using other post.

Comment: if i use that IP address i am getting error llike this "Error: IO_ERROR : java.io.IOException: Error while connecting Oozie server. No of retries = 1. Exception = Could not authenticate, Authentication failed, status: -1, message: null
"

Comment: You don't know where Oozie server is? Then how can you give the correct url?

Comment: oozie server is in another system, if i use that url i am getting above error.

Comment: Sounds like you're using Kerberos and you've not ran `kinit`

Comment: i am new to this. please help me out with this problem.

Comment: http://www.hadoopadmin.co.in/bigdata/run-pig-script-though-oozie/ i am following this tutorial.

Comment: Yes, but your Hadoop cluster is requiring authentication

Comment: if i use "kinit admin" command, then i am getting 
"kinit: Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'EXAMPLE.COM' while getting initial credentials"

Comment: You should talk to however installed Oozie, then to see how you can get authenticated because what you've tried so far is not wrong

Comment: without this, is there any other way ?

Comment: i am not able to run "oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -status" also, connection refused exception i am getting.

Comment: You get connection refused because the url is not the correct Oozie server. Whatever you used to get authentication error is correct, but you simply need authorization, but that's not something anyone here can help you with

Comment: please suggest me that how can i get authentication?

Comment: I can't. Like I said, talk to your server administrator